# Kafka ksql simple join does not work

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have rekeyed data in stream and table i use Confluent 4.1

1) Create Stream

```
   CREATE STREAM session_details_stream (Media varchar ,SessionIdTime varchar,SessionIdSeq long) with (kafka_topic = 'sessionDetails', value_format = 'json');
```

2) create rekeyed stream  as this script does not work, but before this its works, why?

```
CREATE STREAM session_details_stream_rekeyed as select Media,SessionIdTime ,SessionIdSeq,CONCAT(SessionIdTime,SessionIdSeq) as root from SESSION_DETAILS_STREAM  partition by root;
```

then i create the next script s

```
CREATE STREAM session_details_stream_update as select Media,SessionIdTime ,SessionIdSeq,CONCAT(SessionIdTime,SessionIdSeq) as root from SESSION_DETAILS_STREAM  partition by SessionIdTime;
CREATE STREAM session_details_stream_rekeyed as select Media,SessionIdTime ,SessionIdSeq,root from session_details_stream_update  partition by root;
```

result from session_details_stream_rekeyed is ok:

```
ksql> select * from session_details_stream_rekeyed;
      1526411486488 | 2018-02-05T15:16:07.113+02:001| tex | 2018-02-05T15:16:07.113+02:001 | 1 | 2018-02-05T15:16:07.113+02:001
```

3) create stream for topics;

```
 CREATE STREAM voip_details_stream (SessionIdTime varchar,SessionIdSeq long) with (kafka_topic = 'voipDetails', value_format = 'json');
 CREATE STREAM voip_details_stream_update as select SessionIdTime ,SessionIdSeq, CONCAT(SESSIONIDTIME,SESSIONIDSEQ) as root from voip_details_stream  partition by SessionIdTime;
 CREATE STREAM voip_details_stream_rekeyed6 as select SessionIdTime ,SessionIdSeq,root from voip_details_stream_update  partition by root;



 ksql> select * from voip_details_stream_rekeyed6;
      1526411479438 | 2018-02-05T15:16:07.113+02:001 | 2018-02-05T15:16:07.113+02:00 | 1 | 2018-02-05T15:16:07.113+02:001
```

4) create a table

```
 CREATE TABLE voipDetails_table_test(SessionIdTime varchar,SessionIdSeq long,root varchar) WITH (kafka_topic='VOIP_DETAILS_STREAM_REKEYED6', value_format='JSON', KEY='root');

 ksql> select * from voip_details_table;

       1526411479438 | 2018-02-05T15:16:07.113+02:001 | 2018-02-05T15:16:07.113+02:00 | 1 | 2018-02-05T15:16:07.113+02:001
```

5)   then i create a left join

```
select  c.root,u.root from session_details_stream_rekeyed c LEFT JOIN voipDetails_table_test u On c.root  = u.root;

   1526411477780 | 2018-02-05T15:16:07.113+02:001 | 2018-02-05T15:16:07.113+02:001 | null
```

where is the problem?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `STREAM` and `TABLE` definitions that you're using for `VOIP_DETAILS_TABLE` and `SESSION_DETAILS_STREAM_REKEYED` please.

Comment: Also can you check the output of the `print` statement that you cite? Normally the timestamp, key, and payload are comma separated.

Comment: By the definitions, I mean the `CREATE STREAM` and `CREATE TABLE` statements that you're issuing.

Comment: Also the result you give, can you provide the `SELECT` statement you ran, since there are five cols. I'm assuming it's `ROWKEY` and `ROWTIME`.

Comment: Basically, to help us help you, it's best if you can make it easy to reproduce the behaviour you're seeing, instead of trying to infer it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr** When doing a stream-table join, your *table* messages must already exist (and must be timestamped) *before* the stream messages. If you re-emit your source stream messages, after the table topic is populated, the join will succeed.

### Example data

Use `kafkacat` to populate topics (paste data to `stdin`)

```
cat > /tmp/msgs <<EOF
{"Media":"Foo","SessionIdTime":"2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST","SessionIdSeq":1}
{"Media":"Foo","SessionIdTime":"2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST","SessionIdSeq":2}
EOF
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -P -t sessionDetails /tmp/msgs


cat > /tmp/msgs <<EOF
{"SessionIdTime":"2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST","SessionIdSeq":1,"Details":"Bar1a"}
{"SessionIdTime":"2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST","SessionIdSeq":1,"Details":"Bar1b"}
{"SessionIdTime":"2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST","SessionIdSeq":2,"Details":"Bar2"}
EOF
kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -P -t voipDetails /tmp/msgs
```

Validate topic contents:

```
Robin@asgard02 ~> kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -C -t sessionDetails
{"Media":"Foo","SessionIdTime":"2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST","SessionIdSeq":1}
{"Media":"Foo","SessionIdTime":"2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST","SessionIdSeq":2}

Robin@asgard02 ~> kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -C -t voipDetails
{"SessionIdTime":"2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST","SessionIdSeq":1,"Details":"Bar1a"}
{"SessionIdTime":"2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST","SessionIdSeq":1,"Details":"Bar1b"}
{"SessionIdTime":"2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST","SessionIdSeq":2,"Details":"Bar2"}
```

### Declare source streams

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM session_details_stream \
      (Media varchar ,SessionIdTime varchar,SessionIdSeq long) \
      WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'sessionDetails', VALUE_FORMAT = 'json');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
ksql> CREATE STREAM voip_details_stream \
      (SessionIdTime varchar,SessionIdSeq long, Details varchar) \
      WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'voipDetails', VALUE_FORMAT = 'json');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
ksql> select * from session_details_stream;
1526553130864 | null | Foo | 2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST | 1
1526553130865 | null | Foo | 2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST | 2
^CQuery terminated
ksql> select * from voip_details_stream;
1526553143176 | null | 2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST | 1 | Bar1a
1526553143176 | null | 2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST | 1 | Bar1b
1526553143176 | null | 2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST | 2 | Bar2
^CQuery terminated
```

### Repartition each topic on SessionIdTime+SessionIdSeq

```
ksql> CREATE STREAM SESSION AS \
      SELECT Media, CONCAT(SessionIdTime,SessionIdSeq) AS root \
      FROM session_details_stream \
      PARTITION BY root;

 Message
----------------------------
 Stream created and running
----------------------------


ksql> SELECT ROWTIME, ROWKEY, root, media FROM SESSION;
1526553130864 | 2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST1 | 2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST1 | Foo
1526553130865 | 2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST2 | 2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST2 | Foo


ksql> CREATE STREAM VOIP AS \
      SELECT CONCAT(SessionIdTime,SessionIdSeq) AS root, details \
      FROM voip_details_stream \
      PARTITION BY root;

 Message
----------------------------
 Stream created and running
----------------------------
ksql>
```

### Declare table

```
ksql> CREATE TABLE VOIP_TABLE (root VARCHAR, details VARCHAR) \
      WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='VOIP', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', KEY='root');

 Message
---------------
 Table created
---------------
ksql> SELECT ROWTIME, ROWKEY, root, details FROM VOIP;
1526553143176 | 2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST2 | 2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST2 | Bar2
1526553143176 | 2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST1 | 2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST1 | Bar1a
1526553143176 | 2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST1 | 2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST1 | Bar1b
```

### Join SESSION stream to VOIP table

```
ksql> SELECT s.ROWTIME, s.root, s.media, v.details \
      FROM SESSION s \
      LEFT OUTER JOIN VOIP_TABLE v ON S.root = V.root;
1526553130864 | 2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST1 | Foo | null
1526553130865 | 2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST2 | Foo | null
```

Leave the above JOIN query running. Re-emit SESSION message to the source topic (using `kafkacat` to send the same messages to `sessionDetails` as above):

```
1526553862403 | 2018-05-17 11:25:33 BST1 | Foo | Bar1a
1526553988639 | 2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST2 | Foo | Bar2
```

Per Rohan Desai on the [Confluent Community Slack](https://slackpass.io/confluentcommunity):

> The problem is that the rowtime of the record from your stream is earlier than the rowtime of the record in your table that you expect it to join with. So when the stream record is processed there is no corresponding record in the table

Looking at the message on the source table for one of the join keys using `ROWTIME` to look at the message timestamp (*not to be confused with the timestamp-based `root`*):

```
ksql> SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') , ROWTIME, root, details from VOIP WHERE root='2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST2';
2018-05-17 11:32:23 | 1526553143176 | 2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST2 | Bar2
```

Compare this to the message on the source session stream topic:

```
ksql> SELECT TIMESTAMPTOSTRING(ROWTIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') , ROWTIME, root, media from SESSION WHERE root='2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST2';
2018-05-17 11:32:10 | 1526553130865 | 2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST2 | Foo
2018-05-17 11:46:28 | 1526553988639 | 2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST2 | Foo
```

The *first* of these (at `11:32:10` / `1526553130865`) is prior to that of the corresponding `VOIP` message (shown above), and resulted in the `null` join result that we first saw. The *second* of these is dated later (`11:46:28` / `1526553988639`) is produced the successful join that we subsequently saw:

```
1526553988639 | 2018-05-17 11:26:33 BST2 | Foo | Bar2
```